# upload files and show preview of each file with options like rotate and remove for each file on front view and while uploading show progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, laravel-8

I am using laravel 8 for my project. The problem is: I need preview of files selected from user before upload with options rotate and remove file. I had built these options but these were working fine with single file and not with multiple file. I was working initially with js/jquery for these appearances but when these did not give appropriate output, I tried to use the ajax.. It is throwing many other problems and I am stuck now..I need to keep option of drag and drop method and get and save file to google drive and dropbox too.. could anyone help or guide please...

below is the code for reference I was working till now..

```
    **DocumentController:**
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;
use ZipArchive;
use Mpdf\Mpdf;

use setasign\Fpdi;

 ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); // 10 minutes

class DocumentController extends Controller
{
    
    public function display_preview(Request $req)
    {
        echo "working";print_r($req->file('fileList'));dd('preview can be set.');
                foreach($req->fileList as $key=>$f)
                {
                    $name=basename($f);
                     $fname=pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                        
                        echo $file_preview="<div class='preview_box alert' style='height: 180px; width: 150px !important; align-content: center;background-Color: lightblue;margin:5px auto;' id='preview_box".$key."'> <button type='button' name='rot_btn' class='r_btn' id='r_btn".$key."' class='align-items-center' name='rotation_style_Right'>   <img src='{{url('assets/images/Rotate_icon.jpg')}}' style='backface-visibility: inherit;height:20px;width:20px;'> </button> <button type='button' style='float: right;' class='closebox close'  data-dismiss='alert' id='closebox".$key."'>&times;</button> <div class='thumbnail_pdf' id='thumbnail_pdf".$key."'> <object data='{{url('assets/img/docx-icon-11.jpg')}}' style='height:35px; width:35px;align-self: center;margin: auto;' ></object>    </div><div id='thumbnail_word' style='word-wrap: break-word;'>". $name ."</div></div> ";
                }
    }
    public function convertUserUploadedWordToPdf(Request $req)
    {
         print_r($req->all());dd('test');
        $this->validate($req, [
                'file' => 'required',
                'file.*' => 'mimes:doc,docx'
        ]);
        $doc_pdf=array();
        if($req->hasFile('file'))
        {
            foreach ($req->file('file') as $key => $doc)
            {
                $name = basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$key]); // $file is set to name without extension
                $fname=pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                $ext=pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $doc->move(public_path('uploads/PDF/'), $_FILES['file']['name'][$key]);
                
           
               
                /* Set the PDF Engine Renderer Path */
               $domPdfPath = base_path('vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
                
                \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($domPdfPath);
                \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');

                        
                //Load word file and convert into pdf

                    $Content = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load(public_path('uploads/PDF/'.$name)); 

                //Save it into PDF 
               $PDFWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($Content,'PDF');
               
               //$file = basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$key], ".docx"); // $file is set to name without extension

                $PDFWriter->save(public_path('uploads/PDF/'.$fname.'.pdf')); //PDF Generated
                if($req->input('rotation_angle'))
                {
                    $rotation_angle=$req->input('rotation_angle');
                    $rotation_angle=360-$rotation_angle;
                            
                    $mpdf = new Mpdf();// Rotating file

                    $pagecount = $mpdf->setSourceFile(public_path('uploads/PDF/'.$fname.'.pdf'));
                    for($i=1;$i<=$pagecount;$i++)
                    {   
                        $tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($i);
                        //$mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
                        $size = $mpdf->getTemplateSize($tplId);
                        if ($size['width'] > $size['height'] && ($rotation_angle == 90 || $rotation_angle== 270)) 
                        {
                            $orientation='P';
                            // Font size 1/3 Height if it landscape
                            //$fontsize = $size['height'] / 3;
                        } 
                        elseif($size['width'] > $size['height'] && ($rotation_angle == 0 || $rotation_angle== 180))
                        {
                            $orientation='L';
                        }
                        elseif($size['width'] < $size['height'] && ($rotation_angle == 0 || $rotation_angle== 180))
                        {
                            $orientation='P';
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            $orientation='L';
                            // Font size 1/3 Width if it portrait
                            //$fontsize = $size['width'] / 3;
                        }
                        
                        $mpdf->AddPage($orientation);
                        
                        
                    //Find the middle of the page to use as a pivot at rotation.
                        $mX = $size['width'] / 2;
                        $mY = $size['height'] / 2;
                    // Set the transparency of the text to really light
                        $mpdf->SetAlpha(1);
                        $mpdf->StartTransform();
                        $mpdf->Rotate($rotation_angle, $mX, $mY);
                        $mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
                        $mpdf->SetXY(0, $mY);
                        $mpdf->StopTransform();
                    // Reset the transparency to default
                        $mpdf->SetDefaultBodyCSS('transform','rotate('.$rotation_angle.'deg)');
                        $mpdf->SetAlpha(1);
                    }
                    $mpdf->Output(public_path('uploads/PDF/'.$fname.'_r.pdf'));
                    array_push($doc_pdf,$fname.'_r.pdf');

                }
                else
                {
                   array_push($doc_pdf,$fname.'.pdf') ;
                }
                 
            }
            if(count($req->file('file'))>1)
            {
            //print_r($doc_pdf);die;
                $zipFileName = 'pdf_docx.zip';
                $zip = new ZipArchive();
                
                if ($zip->open(public_path('uploads/PDF/'.$zipFileName),ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) 
                {
                    // Add File in ZipArchive
                    foreach($doc_pdf as $file)
                    {
                        if (! $zip->addFile(public_path('uploads/PDF/'.$file),$file))
                        {
                            echo 'Could not add file to ZIP: ' . $file;
                        }
                    }
                    $zip->close();
                }
                else 
                {
                    echo 'Could not open ZIP file.';
                }
                return back()
            ->with('success','You have successfully converted files.')
            ->with('file',$zipFileName);      
            }
            else
            {
                if($req->input('rotation_angle'))
                {
                        return back()
                    ->with('success','You have successfully converted file.')
                    ->with('file',$fname.'_r.pdf'); 
                }
                else
                {
                     return back()
                    ->with('success','You have successfully converted file.')
                    ->with('file',$fname.'.pdf');
                }     
            }

        }
        
        
    }
    public function pdfview($pdf_file)
    {
        $filePath = public_path('uploads/PDF/'.$pdf_file);
        $headers = ['Content-Type: application/octet-stream'];
        $fileName = $pdf_file;

        return response()->download($filePath, $fileName, $headers);
    }


    public function insertPdfConversion()
    {
        return view('pdf_conversion');
    }
```

Route:(web.php)

```
//Word to pdf Conversion..

Route::get('/pdf_conversion', [App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController::class, 'insertPdfConversion'])->name('pdf_conversion');
Route::post('/pdf_conversion',[App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController::class, 'convertUserUploadedWordToPdf'])->name('wordtopdf_conversion');
Route::post('/get_preview',[App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController::class,'display_preview'])->name('get_preview');
$router->get('/pdfview/{pdf_file}',[
 'uses' => 'App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@pdfview',
 'as'   => 'pdfview'
]);
```

blade file:

```
@include('header1');
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.Add_file{
    color: white;
}
.Add_file::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.Add_file::before{
    content: '+';
    align-content: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, blue, pink);
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 30px;
    
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     font-size: 30px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}
.Add_file:hover::before {
  border-color: black;
}
.Add_file:active::before {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, white, blue);
}
.file_input {
  color:white;
}
.file_input::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    visibility: hidden;

}
.file_input::before{
    content: 'Select Word files';
    align-content: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, blue, pink);
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
     -webkit-user-select: none;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18pt;
    min-height: 50px;
    min-width: 250px;
}


.file_input:hover::before {
  border-color: black;
}
.file_input:active::before {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, white, blue);
}

.dropzone {
  height: 100px!important;
  width:  250px;
  align-content: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.thumbnail_pdf{
    height: 100px;
    width: 70px;
    align-self:center;
    background-color: white;
    align-content: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin:auto;
}

    .disabledbutton {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

</style>
<!-- Main Work Area-->
<div style="width:100%;min-height:auto;align-content:center;text-align: center;margin:15% 0%;">
     @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
             
        </div>
        @endif

     @if (count($errors) > 0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif

    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Convert WORD to PDF</h1>
    <h4 style="text-align: center;">Make DOC and DOCX files easy to read by converting them to PDF.</h4>


    
    <form class="form-group" method="POST" action="{{ route('wordtopdf_conversion') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="dropForm">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <div class="row">
            @csrf
            <div class="col-sm-12 mt-4 align-items-center ">

                <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" id="choose_file">
                
                    <input type="file" name="file[]" id="imgInp" class="file_input" accept=".doc,.docx" multiple="" >
                    <input type="text" name="rotation_angle" id="rot_ang" value="" hidden>

                </div>
                <span>
                    @if ($downloadpdf = Session::get('file'))
                    <a class="btn btn-primary align-items-center" href="{!! route('pdfview', ['pdf_file'=>$downloadpdf]) !!}" target="_blank">Download PDF</a> 
                    @endif
                </span>
                
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            

            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 " >
                <div id="preview-template"></div>
                <div class="row" id="files_preview" style="margin:auto;" ></div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="ad_files col-md-2 col-sm-2" style="display:none;min-width:20%;min-height:60%;align-content:center;float:right;margin:0 auto;"> 
                    <input type="file" name="file[]" id="ad_doc" class="Add_file" accept=".doc,.docx" multiple="" >

            </div>

            <div id="tools" class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4" style="float:right; display:none;">
                <div class="card" style="height: 100%;width: 80%;margin: 0px;float: right;padding: 0px;">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <span class="center-block">Word to PDF</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <!--<input type="submit" name="Conversions" id="startUpload" class="btn btn-primary" value="Convert Word To PDF ">-->
                            <button type="submit" name="Conversions" id="startUpload" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Convert Word To PDF <img src="{{url('assets/images/arrow.png')}}" style="height:30px;width: 30px;backface-visibility: hidden;">
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
            
    <!--<button id="uploadFile">Upload Files</button>-->
</div>
<!-- Work area ended-->


<script>

    
/*function rotateRight()
{
    rotation += 90; // add 90 degrees, you can change this as you want
      if (rotation == 360) { 
        // 360 means rotate back to 0
        rotation = 0;
      }
    var img = document.querySelector('#thumbnail_pdf');
        img.style.transform = 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)';
        document.querySelector("#rot_ang").value=rotation;
  
}*/

//Disabling autoDiscover
/*Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$(function() {
    //Dropzone class
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone", {
       url:"{{ route('wordtopdf_conversion') }}",
        paramName: "file",
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        maxFilesize: 10,
        maxFiles: 10,
        acceptedFiles: ".doc,.docx",
        autoProcessQueue: false
    });

    $('#tools').css("display","block");
    $('#r_btn').css("display","block");
    $('#choose_file').css("display","none");
    $('#thumbnail_word').innerHTML=myDropzone.files.name;
    $('#preview_box').css("display","block");
    $('#preview_box').css("backgroundColor","lightblue");
    $('#startUpload').click(function(){           
        myDropzone.processQueue();
    });
});*/

//..... Dropzone Script is started..

var dropzone = new Dropzone('#dropForm', {
  previewTemplate: document.querySelector('#preview-template').innerHTML,
  parallelUploads: 5,
  thumbnailHeight: 220,
  thumbnailWidth: 220,
  multipleUpload:true,
  maxFilesize: 5,
  filesizeBase: 1000,
  autoQueue:true,
  thumbnail: function(file, dataUrl) {
    if (file.previewElement) {
      file.previewElement.classList.remove("dz-file-preview");
      var images = file.previewElement.querySelectorAll("[data-dz-thumbnail]");
      for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var thumbnailElement = images[i];
        thumbnailElement.alt = file.name;
        thumbnailElement.src = dataUrl;

      }
      setTimeout(function() { file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-image-preview"); }, 1);
    }
    
         $('#thumbnail_word').innerHTML = myDropzone.files.name; 
  }
});
// Now fake the file upload, since GitHub does not handle file uploads
// and returns a 404
var minSteps = 6,
    maxSteps = 60,
    timeBetweenSteps = 100,
    bytesPerStep = 100000;
dropzone.uploadFiles = function(files) {
  var self = this;
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    totalSteps = Math.round(Math.min(maxSteps, Math.max(minSteps, file.size / bytesPerStep)));
    for (var step = 0; step < totalSteps; step++) {
      var duration = timeBetweenSteps * (step + 1);
      setTimeout(function(file, totalSteps, step) {
        return function() {
          file.upload = {
            progress: 100 * (step + 1) / totalSteps,
            total: file.size,
            bytesSent: (step + 1) * file.size / totalSteps
          };
          self.emit('uploadprogress', file, file.upload.progress, file.upload.bytesSent);
          if (file.upload.progress == 100) {
            file.status = Dropzone.SUCCESS;
            self.emit("success", file, 'success', null);
            self.emit("complete", file);
            self.processQueue();
            //document.getElementsByClassName("dz-success-mark").style.opacity = "1";
          }
        };
       
      }(file, totalSteps, step), duration);
    }
  }
}
//----DropZone Script is ended..
    
    $(document).ready(function()
    {   
        $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
        doc_arr = []; 
        //if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) 
        //{

            $("#imgInp").on("change", function(e) 
            {
                //var files1 = e.target.files;
                var files1 = $(this).val();
                alert(files1)
                $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    url: "{{route('get_preview')}}",
                    
                    data:{ // change data to this object
                        _token : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), 
                            fileList:files1
                        },
                         dataType: "text",
                    success:function(result)
                    {
                        alert(result)
                        $('#files_preview').append(result); 
                        $('#tools').css('display','block');
                        $('#imgInp').css('display','none');
                        $('.ad_files').css('display',"block");
                    },
                    error: function (request, message, error) 
                    {
                        //handleException(request, message, error);
                        alert('error in process');
                        alert(error);
                    },
                     cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                })
        
                /*for (var i = 0; i < files1.length; i++)
                {
                
                        //alert(files1[i].name)
                     

                    var a = files1[i];
                    //var fileReader = new FileReader();
                    //fileReader.onload = (function(e) 
                    //{
                            //var file = e.target.files;

                        file_preview="<div class='preview_box alert' style='height: 180px; width: 150px !important; align-content: center;background-Color: lightblue;margin:5px auto;' id='preview_box"+i+"'> <button type='button' name='rot_btn' class='r_btn' id='r_btn"+i+"' class='align-items-center' name='rotation_style_Right'>   <img src='{{url('assets/images/Rotate_icon.jpg')}}' style='backface-visibility: inherit;height:20px;width:20px;'> </button> <button type='button' style='float: right;' class='closebox close'  data-dismiss='alert' id='closebox"+i+"'>&times;</button> <div class='thumbnail_pdf' id='thumbnail_pdf"+i+"'> <object data='{{url('assets/img/docx-icon-11.jpg')}}' style='height:35px; width:35px;align-self: center;margin: auto;' ></object>  </div><div id='thumbnail_word' style='word-wrap: break-word;'>"+ a.name +"</div></div> ";
                        
                        $('#files_preview').append(file_preview);*/
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        /*
                        const doc = {
                          Name: a.name,
                          Rotation: rotation,
                          
                          file_detail: function() {
                            return this.Name + " : " + this.Rotation;
                          }
                        };                      
                        doc_arr[i]= doc.file_detail();*/
                        
                        $('.closebox').click(function()
                        {
                                                                 
                            //files1[i].name="";
                            /*               
                            if(files1.length == 0)
                            {
                                $("#tools").addClass("disabledbutton");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $("#tools").removeClass("disabledbutton");
                            }   */
                                            
                        })
                    //});
                    //fileReader.readAsDataURL(a);
                                                                               
                //}
                        
                
                 
                
            })
                
                        
        //}
        let rotation = 0;
            $('button[name=rot_btn]').click(function()
            {   
                alert(123)          //rotateRight()
                rotation += 90; // add 90 degrees, you can change this as you want
                if (rotation == 360) 
                { 
                               // 360 means rotate back to 0
                    rotation = 0;
                }
                            
                $(this).siblings('.thumbnail_pdf').css('transform','rotate('+rotation+'deg)');
                a=$(this).siblings('.thumbnail_word').innerHTML;
                //doc_arr.push( a+' : '+rotation);
                //docJSON = JSON.stringify(doc_arr);
                $('#rot_ang').val(a+' : '+rotation);
            });     
        
    })
/*
function load_features()
{
    const [file] = imgInp.files;

  var fullPath = $("#imgInp").val();  

    var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    document.getElementById('thumbnail_word').innerHTML = filename;
    document.getElementById('tools').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('r_btn').style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector('#imgInp').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('preview_box').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('preview_box').style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
    document.querySelector('.ad_files').style.display = "block";
}*/

</script>
@include('footer');
```

Comment: "It is throwing many other problems" - like what? half your javascript is commented out, could that be the problem?

Comment: [Violation] 'change' handler took 2759ms
jquery-3.6.0.js:10109 POST http://localhost:8000/get_preview 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-3.6.0.js:10109
ajax @ jquery-3.6.0.js:9690
(anonymous) @ pdf_conversion:419
dispatch @ jquery-3.6.0.js:5430
elemData.handle @ jquery-3.6.0.js:5234
jquery-3.6.0.js:10033 [Violation] 'load' handler took 4367ms
jquery-3.6.0.js:10109 XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:8000/get_preview".

Comment: 500 (Internal server Error), 419 (unknown status), These errors are received in console and program is not working... applied the solution given in stackoverflow.. but the error is same... I am fresher in this field.. Your guidelines would be highly appreciated... Please help..